# Why is ifstream failing when reading mixed data?

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have a text file with words and integers. The task is to read only integers from it ignore words. This is an example of such file:

```
seven 7
```

I declare an int variable and try to read the ifstream into it (echoing the state of ifstream):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    int num = -1;
    std::ifstream ifs("file.in");

    std::cout << ifs << std::endl;
    ifs >> num;
    std::cout << ifs << std::endl;
    if ( ifs.fail() )
        ifs.clear();
    std::cout << ifs << std::endl;
    ifs >> num;
    std::cout << ifs << std::endl;

    std::cout << num << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

To which I get an output:

```
1
0
1
0
-1
```

It's obvious that 'ifs' fails when trying to read a word into an int variable. My question is why does it fail the second time after being cleared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first failure doesn't advance the stream position, so the second tries again with exactly the same results. You'll need to skip over the unwanted word, either reading it into a string or using `ignore`.